# Loading content in a target div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So the first part of the code works fine as it should be, the two grid and list view loads in the views-div when clicked, however, I want a default view shown in the views-div using jquery, I tried loading using clone and prependto but it doesn't work. any suggestion on how to do this?

note: the content I'm loading from the backend has tags and ID's so if I use the html markup to show a default content in the views-div the content repeats. So I'm hoping if use jquery to load content, the repeating will not occur.

here's a demo http://jsfiddle.net/soulsurfer/eta0uyye/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.iw-grid-select, .iw-list-select').on('click', function() {
    var aID = $(this).attr('href');
    var elem = $('' + aID).html();
    $('#iw-grid-view').fadeOut("slow", 1000);
    $('#iw-listview').fadeOut("slow", 1000);
    $('#iw-views-div').html(elem);

});

$( "#iw-grid-view" ).contents().find( ".iw-grid-list-col" ).clone().prependTo("#iw-views-div");
});
```

Comment: Instead you can just try to trigger the click handler like `$('.iw-grid-select, .iw-list-select').first().trigger('click');` to load the contents of the first element

Comment: Is it possible for you create a **demo here in snippet**?

Comment: @divy3993 yes I can. here you go http://jsfiddle.net/soulsurfer/eta0uyye/

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks a lot, your solution worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution could be is to trigger a click event

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.iw-grid-select, .iw-list-select').on('click.view', function() {
    var aID = $(this).attr('href');
    var elem = $('' + aID).html();
    $('#iw-grid-view').fadeOut("slow", 1000);
    $('#iw-listview').fadeOut("slow", 1000);
    $('#iw-views-div').html(elem);
  }).first().trigger('click.view');


});
```

```css
.iw-listview,
.iw-grid-view {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="iw-filter-col ">
  <a href="#iw-grid-view " class="iw-grid-select ">grid view link</a>&nbsp;
  <a href="#iw-listview " class="iw-list-select ">list view link</a>
</div>
<div class="row iw-listing-view-row">
  <div class="iw-grid-view" id="iw-grid-view">Grid view content</div>
  <div id="iw-listview" class="iw-listview">list view content</div>
  <div class="iw-views-div" id="iw-views-div">Content loading column</div>
  <div id="loading"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this has been resolved, but just in case anyone was wondering where OP went wrong, I have a theory.

This:

```
$( "#iw-grid-view" ).contents().find( ".iw-grid-list-col" ).clone().prependTo("#iw-views-div");
```

Should be changed to this:

```
$( "#iw-grid-view" ).find( ".iw-grid-list-col" ).clone().prependTo("#iw-views-div");
```

If the `.iw-grid-list-col` element was an immediate child of `#iw-grid-view`, then `find()` wouldn't have found it when called on the return value of `contents()`. This is because `find()` searches through *descendants* of elements. The return value of `contents()`, in this case, would have included the `.iw-grid-list-col` element and `find()` would not have found it since it was a member of the array that `find()` was called on, rather than a descendant of a member of the array.

Removing `contents()` from that chain of function calls allows `find()` to search all of the descendants of `#iw-grid-view` instead of just the descendants of its immediate children.